# TFS 2013 Bugs vs PBI per Sprint chart

Tags: charts, tfs

I want to get a report of the number of PBIs vs Bugs in every Sprint - think of it as a stacked column report where each column is a sprint. What makes things a little interesting is our business stakeholders report both bugs and gaps/enhancements as bugs. We differentiate it by “Defect Category” – Bug or Gap.

I don't see a way to create a chart where the x-axis is Sprint. Is there a way to create such a chart in TFS. The trend charts only allow 4 week view. I want to get a sprint by sprint view since the start of the project

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no this kind of build-in chart in TFS.

You may have to achieve this by using Custom Reports. Either using [SQL Server Reporting Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/overview#sql-server-reporting-services-reports-tfs) (SSRS) or Work Item Queries and [Excel reports](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/overview#excel-reports-tfs). SSRS is  for most of the “complex” reports, excel can provide valuable information that is sometimes hard to find in the TFS Warehouse.

More detail steps you can refer these blogs:

- [Using Custom Reports in TFS: Part 1 – Introduction in TFS Data](https://roadtoalm.com/2012/02/22/using-custom-reports-in-tfs-part-1-introduction-in-tfs-data/)
- [Using Custom Reports in TFS: Part 2 – What tools can I use to
  present some data?](https://roadtoalm.com/2012/02/29/using-custom-reports-in-tfs-part-2-what-tools-can-i-use-to-present-some-data/)
- [Using Custom Reports in TFS: Part 3 – How to set up my reporting
  environment and structure](https://roadtoalm.com/2012/03/13/using-custom-reports-in-tfs-part-3-how-to-set-up-my-reporting-environment-and-structure/)